# How to make an exe in cmd from a .py not close the window when it ends?

Tags: cmd, python-3.7

I'm traying to make an app, its too many lines to output here a simple version. I don't know if there is something wrong with the dll's or the .py, with auto-py-to-exe I made it an executable,& it gave some errors (torch libreries not found), but when running the program (exe), it doesn't seem to have any problem (it runds as the py program in the terminal).

So, does the terminal closes by its own when the script is finished? if so; how can I make the program not close till I press a key or force the close?

If the terminal doesn't close by it's own, could those dll be the problem?

Please let me know if the terminal closes by its own (the script is very slow and it takes 45 min for me to see if it works or not).

Thanks.

I've uninstalled and installed torch and torchvision modules (but there's always an errors with some libreries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm going to use is:

```
import os
......
os.system("pause")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a builtin function `input` that allows you to customize the prompt that the user will get:

```
input("Press enter to exit.")
```

This will show the prompt `Press enter to exit.`